# Using Rails link_to for links that post

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, post, ruby-on-rails-3.2, link-to

I have a link that I need to submit a post request with. Normally, I'd use jQuery and prevent the link's default behavior and then submit a form to the destination. This seems like something Rails should be able to help me out with. Sure enough, the `link_to` method has an option for specifying a POST http method:

```
link_to "Profile", 'http://example.com/profile', method: :post
```

That works, but I need to add 2 parameters too. I tried:

```
link_to "Profile", 'http://example.com/profile', method: post, param1: 'value1', param2: 'value2'
```

That just added those parameters to the `<a>` HTML element, but didn't submit those when clicking the link:

```
<a rel="nofollow" param1="value1" param2="value2" data-method="post" href="http://example.com/profile">Profile</a>
```

Is there a way to do a POST request with parameters using `link_to` or any other Rails method? I'm using Rails 3.2.9.

Comment: don't think you can do that. probably best doing it in your controller with net/http or HTTParty?

Comment: Can't do it in my controller, user needs to be directed to the other site. Looks like you're right though, there isn't a built-in link mechanism to do this for me.

Answer (score 166, accepted):

The short answer is that if what you mean by "parameters" is form fields, then you simply can't do this (at least not in a straightforward way that I can see). You should instead use a form with a submit button, styled to look like a link (if that's what you want it to look like).

If on the other hand you had meant *query* parameters, then this would work:

```
link_to "Profile", profile_path(@profile.id, param1: 'value1', param2: 'value2'), method: :post
```

Comment: Just updated my question, I'm actually using an external URL for these links.

Comment: I've added a note basically saying that what you want to do is not possible using a link. You need a form with a submit button.

Comment: It's important to note that if a user has javascript disabled the link will default to a "GET" request.

Answer (score 16):

Note that if the user has JS disabled or you have removed the unobtrusive JS libraries that come by default, `link_to` will be silently submitted via a `GET` request.

In general, I am not very fond of having links that perform `POST` requests. I think that's the role of a form and a button.

Thus, an easy (and safer) alternative is to use the Rails [button_to](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-button_to) helper:

```
button_to 'Profile', profile_path(@profile, param1: 'value1', param2: 'value2')
```

`button_to` also supports the `method` option but as it defaults to `post` so I've just omitted it.

Comment: Agreed with Kostas. Moreover, link_to with method post doesn't work well on Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 10):

For Rails 7 with Turbo

```
link_to "Profile", profile_path(@profile), data: { turbo_method: "post" }
```

Answer (score 8):

You can encode parameters in the URL this way :

```
link_to "Profile", 'http://example.com/profile?' + {param1: 'value1', param2: 'value2'}.to_param, method: :post
```

If it does not fit your needs you are better use a form than a `link_to`.

Comment: This is indeed a very nice way to add the parameters.

Comment: Doesn't work for my needs, the parameters need to be POST parameters. But thanks, I didn't know about the to_param method. You also need a `?` after profile.

Comment: Ok I understand, then I think you have to write a form. You can write an helper method which will build this form if you need to repeat this logic several times.

Comment: Notwithstanding that this doesn't answer the OP's question, you should use a url helper for this as in @shioyama's answer

Comment: @BenWest : the helper was not initially used and I assumed it was meaningful (it may have been an external URL for example)

Answer (score 1):

In order to POST data, you need a form.  However, you don't need a submit button.  If you want this to look like a link for some reason, you can actually make it a link that submits the form via JavaScript.  In the example below, the POST resource is just a REST action that does not require any fields so there are no form input controls.  If you wanted to post some data, just put hidden input fields in the form.

```
<%= form_tag('http://something_postable', :method => :post, :class => 'internal') %></form>
<%= link_to_function('Label for Link', 'previous("form").submit()', :title => 'Hover text for link') %>
```

The form is assigned a class so you can style it or hide it via CSS (e.g. 'display: inline')

Answer (score 1):

The parameters and the http method should be together `{param1: 'value1', param2: 'value2', :method: :post}`

```
<%= link_to "Profile", profile_path(@profile), {param1: 'value1', param2: 'value2', method: :post} %>
```