# Sending data with POST via link_to tag

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Have been dealing with this issue for some time and searched through the whole net, but nothing seems to be useful.

I'm trying to post data through a link_to tag like this:

```
// get_doctors.html.erb
<%= link_to "Ekle", patient_add_doctor_path(id: @patient.id), data: { doctor: doctor.id }, method: :post  %>
```

However, at the controller, I can not reach the data in my controller.

```
// patients_controller.rb

def add_doctor
    patient = Patient.find(params[:id].to_i)
    doctor  = Doctor.find(params[:doctor].to_i) // problem is here!
    patient.doctors << doctor
end
```

It gives me the error that params[:doctor] is 0.

**Couldn't find Doctor with 'id'=0 [WHERE "users"."type" IN ('Doctor')]**

Have tried many different ways. Tried also this,

```
<%= link_to "Ekle", patient_add_doctor_path(id: @patient.id), doctor: doctor.id, method: :post  %>
```

which is also did not worked.

Comment: try this `<%= link_to "Ekle", patient_add_doctor_path(id: @patient.id, doctor: doctor.id), method: :post  %>`

Comment: this should give you some clearity http://stackoverflow.com/a/13414818/753705

Comment: I know it's ugly but you might have to render forms for each link you want to post data. Would definitely like to see a nicer way to do this.

Comment: @abhishek77in I was going to do that but gave up for the same reason you have just stated :(

Comment: `link_to` with `method: :post` should be creating a form for you, with the data passed as hidden attributes. Your original link_to tag seems right. Can you inspect the rendered page and paste what HTML Rails is generating for your tag?

Comment: @Athar It worked like a charm. This may sound amateur but is it possible to pass them as hidden variables, without showing them in the URL? Just asking out of curiosity.

Comment: How you are getting doctor variable here `doctor.id`?

Comment: as @abhishek77in said,  you have to use form for that. create a form and set the doctor as hidden_field in it and the values will not be part of url.

Comment: @RobertNubel of course. Here is the generated HTML. 
`<a data-doctor="2" rel="nofollow" data-method="post" href="http://localhost:3000/patients/3/doctors">Ekle</a>`

Comment: @Pavan by `@doctors.each do |doctor|` block. Forgot to include that, sorry.

Comment: @BurakÖzmen: oh, I see. The `data:` attribute doesn't specify attributes that will be sent with the request, but instead custom `data-foo` attributes on the `a` tag... which doesn't get you anywhere. Athar's suggestion is your best bet short of creating a form tag.