# Can I use Rails link_to to make a POST instead of a button_to?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, svg

I am using the inline_svg gem to render SVGs for my icons.
My view code looks like this:

```
<div class="icon">
  <%= link_to inline_svg(listing.favorite_icon, class: "svg"), favorite_listing_path(id: listing.id), method: :post  %>
</div>
```

I have a heart icon that, when the user clicks it, a `POST` should be made to the Rails `favorite` route.  I tested this in Postman and it does correctly work outside of my view.  But, inside of my view, clicking favorite generates a `GET`.

I know I can use `button_to` instead of `link_to` and the `POST` will then happen..BUT...`button_to` doesn't render my SVG properly (see attached pics).

So I can go one of two ways...can someone help me get my link_to to `POST`? Or can someone give me a clue as to why my SVG doesn't render correctly with `button_to`?

With `link_to`:

[image: Before]

With `button_to`:

[image: After]

UPDATE:  Here are some things I have tried...clicking still results in a `GET`.  **Also, I'm on Rails 4.2 if that makes a difference at all.**

```
<%= link_to "hi", controller: "listings", action: "favorite", id: listing.id, method: :post  %>

<%= link_to(inline_svg(listing.favorite_icon, class: "svg"), controller: "listings", action: "favorite", id: listing.id, method: :post)  %>
```

```
<%= link_to(favorite_listing_path(id: listing.id), method: :post)  do %>
  <div class="icon">
    <%= inline_svg(listing.favorite_icon, class: "svg") %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I don't know if this will help or not but try this: `<%= link_to(inline_svg(listing.favorite_icon, class: "svg"), favorite_listing_path(id: listing.id), method: :post)  %>` or may be you can use a `link_to` block using the `do end`.

Comment: @Deep Point them to the [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to) and you could convert that comment into a decent answer.

Comment: As far as the `button_to` stuff goes, you probably want to throw in a `.html_safe` call to tell Rails that your SVG string doesn't need to be HTML-escaped.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13414663/using-rails-link-to-for-links-that-post

Comment: I think best way is to use link_to, and apply button css on it.

Comment: @muistooshort Actually I am not sure so I have just posted the comment. Kelly you can refer to the document link provided in the second comment. Or this is another one: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to

Comment: for verbs :post, :delete, :patch, and :put., if the user has JavaScript disabled, the request will fall back to using GET. So add one more option. `remote: true `

Comment: @Deep, tried both of your suggestions.  Neither worked.  :(

Comment: @Brad Werth, I saw that SO post (and many others as well).  I even copied the exact line (so abandoning the SVG) and changed just the path, but my server does a `GET`.  Could it be that I set up the path incorrectly?  Although, trying it with Postman works.  Also I'm on Rails 4.  Does that make a difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this out.  When I started the Rails project, I stripped out Rails-Jquery.  I didn't realize the `{ method: POST }` uses this.

Answer (score 1):

This post is pretty old, but I wanted to comment with what ended up working for me after coming across it.

```
<%= link_to story_favourite_path(@story), method: :post do %>
    <%= render inline: Rails.root.join('public/bookmark-regular.svg').read %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

For verbs :post, :delete, :patch, and :put., if the user has JavaScript disabled, the request will fall back to using GET. So add one more option. `remote: true` to over come from your first issue.

```
<div class="icon">
  <%= link_to inline_svg(listing.favorite_icon, class: "svg"), favorite_listing_path(id: listing.id), method: :post, remote: true  %>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.  This didn't work.  It's still doing a `GET`.  Also, I tried wrapping everything after the link_to in parens but no luck.