# How to add Rails-Jquery back to Rails app?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm working with ROR 4.  I posted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32431219/can-i-use-rails-link-to-to-make-a-post-instead-of-a-button-to) about how my link_to wouldn't `POST` correctly using `{ method: :post }`.

I figured out this was because I removed the Rails-Jquery gem when I first set up my app (this is a side project, I hadn't planned on using Javascript/jQuery or so I thought!).

In an effort to get my `POST` working, I added the gem back to Gemfile.  The file now looks like this:

```
    source 'https://rubygems.org'

    gem 'aws-sdk'
    gem 'faker'
    gem 'jquery-rails'
    gem 'inline_svg'
    gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
    gem 'nokogiri'
    gem 'paperclip'
    gem 'pg'
    gem 'rails', '~> 4.2.0'
    gem 'sass-rails'
```

I did a `bundle install`.

I added the below code to `application.js`:

```
    //= require jquery
    //= require jquery_ujs
    //= require_tree .
```

What am I missing?  jQuery still isn't loading in the `Network` tab in Chrome.

I'm guessing I must have changed another config setting on setup (5 weeks ago) that I am now forgetting.

UPDATE:  I also removed `turbolinks` during the main setup.  Is that needed for jQuery to work?

Comment: try adding Jquery file manually in assets/javascript folder and see ....

Comment: what does your application.html.erb look like?

Comment: @JeffD23 that was it!  Want to add a suggested solution and I will accept it?

Comment: thought that was it, posted the answer below as well

Comment: Thanks for the help too @HaiderAli.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you removed javascript during the initial setup, you are probably missing this from the head of your `application.html.erb` layout.

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>
```

Comment: Thanks!!  That was the problem.