# param is missing or the value is empty: plant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have added a custom action in my controller called transplant.  I simply want to render a dropdown form to select where to be located based on the 'tray_id'

my routes look like this:

```
resources :plants do
    member do
      get 'transplant'
    end
    resources :plantdats, :plant_cycles, :tasks
 end
```

My controller looks like this:

```
before_action :set_plant, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :transplant]

def transplant

  if @plant.update(plant_params)
    redirect_to @plant
    flash[:success] = "Transplanted successfully"
  end
end
def set_plant
    @plant = Plant.find(params[:id])
end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
def plant_params
   params.require(:plant).permit(:title, :notes, :category_id, :tray_id, images_files: [])
end
```

Here is my button calling the action

```
<%= link_to 'TRANSPLANT', transplant_plant_path(@plant), class: "btn btn-raised btn-info hoverable" %>
```

**Here is my transplant page** _transplant.html.erb

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
    <div class="jumbotron">
      <%= form_for(@plant, html: {class: 'form-horizontal'}) do |f| %>
          <% if @plant.errors.any? %>
              <div id="error_explanation">
                <h2><%= pluralize(@plant.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this grow from being saved:</h2>

                <ul>
                  <% @plant.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
                      <li><%= message %></li>
                  <% end %>
                </ul>
              </div>
          <% end %>
          <%= f.label 'NAME' %>
          <%= f.hidden_field :tray_id, value: params[:tray_id] %>
          <% if params[:tray_id].nil? %>
              <%= f.collection_select(:tray_id, Tray.all, :id, :title) %></br></br>
          <% end %>

          <%= f.submit class: 'btn btn-raised hoverable btn-success' %>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT**
After implementing the route to post 'transplant
and changing my link code to

```
<%= link_to "TRANSPLANT", transplant_plant_path(@plant, tray_id: @plant.tray_id), method: "post", class: "btn btn-raised hoverable" %>
```

I still get the same error.  It points right to the plant_params code in my controller.

These are the params that are being passed:

```
{"_method"=>"post",
 "authenticity_token"=>"fhSKt2DpgTwt1J4HsoBqYFSs0B9+pgSvDDxrS/u6yo4c3gvSxYlrrFDmhbPXq+cMho/eTHY+194WZ8zpcb1txA==",
 "id"=>"1",
 "format"=>"1"}
```

Im simply trying to update the `:tray_id`

Ive been at this all day, can anyone help with the error that Im getting?

Comment: Please show the log for the action, including all parameters sent.

Comment: Please also chose the code for the transplant action and view.

Comment: Thought I added that part of the code, guess i slipped on that :/

Comment: You're trying to implement an action that requires form parameters, but you can't actually do that with a link_to action: See this answer to [Using Rails link_to for links that post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13414818/6263819) for  more information.

Comment: @MichaelGaskill This actually helped.  Thanks for the answer.  I just rendered the form in the view and it works great now. Thanks a ton.

Comment: You have a couple of options: a) build a complete form solution, 2) create a form with only hidden fields and have a click handler for the link that submits the form, but still looks like just a link.  Option (a) is straightforward, but might not fit the UI that you want.  Option (b) is more "interesting", and requires some Javascript coding.  I can help with (b) if that's what you're leaning toward.

Comment: @MichaelGaskill thanks for the offer and the answer.  I believe its better for the ui in my app to render the form.  It checks out and works exactly how I want it to now.

Answer (score 2):

You should probably provide your code for your transplant action and view. Based on what you provided, it seems like you're trying to build a link, which changes the *tray* of a *plant* when clicked. If that's the case, transplant should probably be a POST route instead of GET. Also, you probably want to provide the tray_id in your post link like this:

```
<%= link_to "TRANSPLANT", transplant_plant_path(@plant, tray_id: {{your id}}), method: "post", class: "..." %>
```

Then you can get tray_id in your transplant through `params[:tray_id]` and  re-associate your plant and tray

Comment: Ill give this a shot, i have added the code for the tranplant view.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially what I was trying to do was not easily done and my approach needed to change.  I simply rendered the transplant form in my view and it works fine now.  Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

Check your routes you just have defined `get` route and your request is `post` after the form submission