# How to pass number_field to controller as parameter?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

The problem is this: I am showing some data to the user in a table and in it has a field of the numeric type that the user fills. However, I do not know how to send the value populated by the user as a parameter to the controller.

I've tried using the following syntax:

```
<td><%= number_field :stock, params[:amount] %></td> ## HERE IS THE PROBLEM

<td><%= link_to 'Buy', new_transaction_path(stock: {stock_id: "#{stock[:id]}", buy_price: "#{stock[:value]}", amount: "#{params[:amount]}", transaction_type: 'buy'}), method: :post %></td>
```

I would like to pass the value that the user informed thought the number_field as a parameter to the controller, but it's not working..

Answer (score 0):

For your case "that the user fills", You have to user a form with a submit button, Here is a relate [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13414663/using-rails-link-to-for-links-that-post), If the value is determined you can use `link_to` otherwise a form is better, Although sometimes I rely on JS or Jquery, I give the `link_to` a specific `id` and I give the input field and `id` too (HTML id), Then make an action listener on the the `<a>` that `link_to` generates, Once user click on it I get the data and submit the data.

The problem for the JS way is that if you are listing a table for more than one link_to for the product with multiple `numeric_field` you have to make sure that the `id` is unique, you can simply doing this by adding `_#{id}` part to the generated `id`.